# Stop crop for cropper js outside the image

Tags: javascript, image, crop

Need to stop crop once the user drags cursor out of the image while cropping.

My problem is once the user moves out of the image and comes back the cropped corners are moved away from the cursor. which should not happen.

Below is the simple demo what I have created.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/css/cropper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/css/main.css">
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/images/picture.jpg" alt="" class="">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/js/cropper.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: your demo works as you want

Comment: My problem is once the user moves out of the image and comes back the cropped corners are moved away from the cursor. which should not happen.

Comment: Oh I see ... that's an awful lot of code to work through, I'll leave it to someone with time on their hands

Comment: ya I know that...not sure if its possible or not.

Comment: it's possible, 100% doable guaranteed - the position of the mouse is a known - obviously there's some sort of relative movement going on when there shouldn't be

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this by setting the viewMode to 1 (default = 0)

Example with the jQuery cropper plugin:

```
var $image = $("#PreviewImage");

$image.cropper({
    viewMode: 1,
    crop: function(event) {
       // do something
    }
});
```